# Independent coordinate system for iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit

I am making a Universal App for iPhone and iPad, and I only have an iPad to test on. I was wondering if there was a way to create a coordinate system that could be used so that UI elements (Self made) or just nodes/sprite nodes in particular can be in relatively the same position on both screens?

As an example, say I have a generic coordinate of 1,1. This could convert to 1,1 on an iPhone, but say 2,3 on an iPad (numbers pulled out of thin air).

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I've recently used was making any position relative to my SKScene width and height. If you define a position as follows:

```
SKScene *myScene;
SKSpriteNode *mySpriteNode;
mySpriteNode.position = CGPointMake(myScene.size.width/35.0, myScene.size.height/20.0);
```

your sprite node will keep the same relative position on any device - assuming your SKScene always occupies the entire screen or the same portion of screen.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of that, thanks! I would assume that font size scaling follows the same rule?

Comment: As the proportion width/height changes from device to device (iPad, iPhone4, iPhone5) you will need to be careful with the size of your sprites. If you apply the example above not only to positions but also to sizes you will lose the proportion between the sprite width and height, which it's likely to be not exactly good. So in this case you might want to make a decision and keep both width and height of your sprites as a relative value to either width or height of your SKScene.